# Classification problem with too many classes and requiring specific outputs

Tags: machine-learning-model, multiclass-classification

I'm trying to solve this exercise in which I have around 10 thousand rows of data with 6 columns of features and one column with over 3 thousand targets. The problem says I need to program an algorithm capable of, when receiving a new line of data, returning the 4 closest targets.

The data is available at:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HV4oF5QJXFB7vHU834TDy-mfSiG4K11V/view?usp=sharing

For example, in the image below, my target is "Nome do Poço".

[image]

I thought of maybe using KNN, because the way the problem is laid out led me straight into it, and trying to return the 4 nearest neighbors. Is there a method to implement that?

Also, is that really the best way to solve this? I think there are too many classes and few data from each, but that's all I was given.

I appreciate any help since I'm pretty new to this field and I just really want to learn how to solve this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting but probably difficult problem.

Thoughts:

- Generally I think you will need to scale the numeric features (e.g. between 0 and 1) for most algorithms, otherwise any method relying on distance will fail.
- Discard any target which has only one example in the training data, possibly even if it has only 2 or 3 instances (?)
- k-NN makes sense imho (probably with scaled features). Note that predicting will take significant time. You can implement it yourself or use [a library](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html).
- I would probably also try a few simple methods, at least decision tree and SVM.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll try to implement it and then compare the results I get when I filter the target variable. I upvoted but it said I need more reputation, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing after some more research:
I used KDTree and BallTree algorithms from scikitlearn and the model.query method to search for the K nearest points from each point in the dataset.

In order to search for new points: I created some new, random points within the space I already had, added them to the dataset and used the algorithm with the new dataset.

Since I wanted to search for the 4 nearest points from each point I had, I used k=5, because k=1 is the point itself.

The algorithm also returns the distances from the point to each closest point. I used this information to create this DataFrame:

-Nome do Poço -> Name of the well (each point is an oil well)

-Ponto 2~5 -> Point 2~5 (Point 1 is the well itself)

-Distância -> Distance

[image: DataFrame with the points and distances]